# Web Api: Model binding working only with JSON not XML

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Here's my action

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    public void Post(int id, Employee employee) //Break point here ...
    {

    }
}
```

When I issue the following **POST** request, things are working perfectly.

```
http://localhost:64946/api/employees/12345

Host: localhost:64946
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 194

{"Id":12345,"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Human"}
```

However, when I change the content-type to be `application/xml`, the employee object is **null**.

```
<Employee xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RequestBinding.Models">
   <FirstName>John</FirstName>
   <Id>12345</Id>
   <LastName>Human</LastName>
</Employee>
```

Am I missing any thing?

## UPDATE

I'm using **Fiddler** to issue request

Thanks for helping

Comment: web api by default return result in xml format .if you not pass any Content-Type in request it send result in xml format

Comment: @VijaySingh it's POST request using fiddler. When I send `json` in the body, it works. But when I change content-type to `application/xml` then replace json by xml in the body, the employee object in the action becomes null.

Answer (score 2):

For this XML

```
<Employee xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RequestBinding.Models">
   <FirstName>John</FirstName>
   <Id>12345</Id>
   <LastName>Human</LastName>
</Employee>
```

to be bound correctly, your `Employee` class in the Web API project must be like this. Namespace must match what is in the request, class must be public, properties must be public, property names must match the XML element names.

```
namespace RequestBinding.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        // Other properties
    }
}
```

Comment: The property match. However, which namespace should much? This `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/RequestBinding.Models"`?

Comment: The namespace of the model must match what is in the request. Since your XML has `RequestBinding.Models`, the namespace of `Employee` must be the same, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Confirmed! I was experiencing the same exact issue with json binding working and xml not. After setting the correct namespace it was fixed. Thanks!  Another point for json being so much simpler to work with heh.

Comment: @Badri Please do you think you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/qiOdmT